# How to add a CSS right border continuously without breaking?

Tags: html, css

How can I add `border-right` continuously without breaking? and make it pass through the `red` **line** without breaking. You can see in my code below how it's breaking.

```css
ul.ul li{
  list-style:none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 19px;
    background: #d3c3e2;
    border: 1px solid red;
} 

ul.ul li .span-1 {
    position: relative;
    width: 102px;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    margin-right:20px;
    padding-right: 12px;
}

ul.ul li .span-2 {
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<ul class="ul">
  <li><span class="span-1">first span content</span><span class="span-12">second c</span></li>
  <li><span class="span-1">first span content</span><span class="span-12">second c</span></li>
  <li><span class="span-1">first span content</span><span class="span-12">second c</span></li>
  <li><span class="span-1">first span content</span><span class="span-12">second c</span></li>
  <li><span class="span-1">first span content</span><span class="span-12">second c</span></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `box-sizing: border-box;` to include this gap into the box, where the border is drawn around.

```css
ul.ul li {
  list-style: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 19px;
  background: #d3c3e2;
  border: 1px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul.ul li .span-1 {
  position: relative;
  width: 102px;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  margin-right: 20px;
  padding-right: 12px;
}

ul.ul li .span-2 {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<ul class="ul">
  <li><span class="span-1">first span content</span><span class="span-12">second c</span></li>
  <li><span class="span-1">first span content</span><span class="span-12">second c</span></li>
  <li><span class="span-1">first span content</span><span class="span-12">second c</span></li>
  <li><span class="span-1">first span content</span><span class="span-12">second c</span></li>
  <li><span class="span-1">first span content</span><span class="span-12">second c</span></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with @Sebastian Speitel's answer here, but I thought your question was just a little ambiguous. If you want the vertical black line to go ***on top of*** the red border, then here is something. I used a pseudo element to create the border because you can't use z-index on a border (but you can on an outline, but you can't have an outline on only one side...). In any case, this looks like it works. There is a "magic number" involved, but it is based on the magic number in your original CSS (102 span width + 20 margin).

```css
* {
     margin: 0px;
     padding: 0px;
    }
    ul {
     position: relative
    }
    ul.ul li{
      list-style:none;
        width: 100%;
        height: 19px;
        background: #d3c3e2;
        border: 1px solid red;
    }     
    ul.ul li .span-1 {
        position: relative;
        width: 102px;
        margin-right:20px;
        padding-right: 12px;
    }   
    ul::before {
     content: "";
     position: absolute;
     height: 100%;
     width: 1px;
     background-color: black;
     left: 122px;
    }
```

```html
    <ul class="ul">
      <li><span class="span-1">first span content</span><span class="span-12">second c</span></li>
      <li><span class="span-1">first span content</span><span class="span-12">second c</span></li>
      <li><span class="span-1">first span content</span><span class="span-12">second c</span></li>
      <li><span class="span-1">first span content</span><span class="span-12">second c</span></li>
      <li><span class="span-1">first span content</span><span class="span-12">second c</span></li>
    </ul>
```